# What will be the Correct Defination of Junction Object in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, salesforce-service-cloud

Recently I was puzzled with the **Junction Object**, well I am clear about this thing, But I require a proper definition with an example, So I can understand it more easily and clear manner.

My actual problem is here:--

**The junction Object provides a many to many relationship, So surely in this relationship, one will be acted as master and other one as child relationship or vice verse. So Now As you also know that when we delete a master entry, then the resultant child entreies will also be removed/deleted which are attached to that Master entry. In our case we have a two sided Master-child relationship. means a Master is a child for an another object and vice verse, So If we deleted an entry in any of the side then it will be deleted/removed other entries also, and as the other other entries removed which are also attach to the previously removed entry side then both side of entries will removed, So I/m just confused in it, that how's our junction Object functionality is working.**

Answer (score 0):

Its Many-to-many relationship. 
For example you have object Position and object Candidate.
Each candidate can be related to many jobs and each Position can be related to many candidates.
For this purpose create a custom object "junction object" with two master-detail relationship fields, linking to the object Job and object Position which represented this kind of relationship.

Comment: Korits, thanks for the response, well can you provide a little more clarification on it, I had updated the Question post above